# Счетчик дат, Или как прибавить дату по условию

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Написал код, который по задумке должен вернуть значение на 3 мес. больше от учетной даты если учетная дата меньше текущей.
Например: Учетная дата 1 января 2019
цикл 1: 1 марта 2019 < 27 марта 2019 => прибавляем дальше
цикл 2: Результат 1 Июня 2019

```
function ExDivNext() {

var date = new Date();
Logger.log(date);
var result;
var D = new Date("11/29/2018");
Logger.log(D);
var i = 0;

do {
i = i + 3;
result =  D.setMonth(D.getMonth() + i);
} while (D < date);


Logger.log(new Date(result));

return (new Date(result));

}
```

Код возвращает 1 сентября 2019, хотя должен вернуть 29 мая 2019, не пойму где ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `Date.setMonth` (как и другие подобные) изменяет сам объект `Date`.
Таким образом у вас на каждой итерации прибавлялось 3 месяца к дате и 3 к переменной `i` - то есть +3 - +6 - +9 в цикле. Переменную `i` можно убрать вовсе и все заработает

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
var D = new Date("11/29/2018");
console.log(D);

do {
  D.setMonth(D.getMonth() + 3);
} while (D < date);

console.log(D);
```